# how to securely use aws-sdk javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, laravel, aws-sdk

I have an application that use ***php/laravel***, in which i use aws_sdk.js to push in **Amazon SQS**. I think that this is not secured because ***JS files*** are loaded in client side who can see the credentials ans access to Amazon SQS.

Any help to solve this problem of security !!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Client-side javascript should not directly depend on the AWS SDK. As you correctly pointed out, you would need to put an IAM Access Key in your JavaScript.

Instead, your client-side application should make a request to the backend, and authenticate it. For example, you could make an AJAX or POST request to your PHP, or you can use another service like AWS API Gateway. Your backend code should then be responsible for putting items in your SQS queue.

Since your backend is now putting items in the SQS, you can then use [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) to assign an IAM role to an EC2 instance or the Lambda function. Then your service can access SQS (assuming the role is set up correctly) with the appropriate SDK and never need to manage IAM access keys since IAM roles do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my position i want to send data from FrontEnd and BackEnd.
Backend is secured cause it is Server side.
Now i want to send Data from FrontEnd, i think using IAM is complicated in my situation cause our application is open for 5000 client can access to it.
So IAM is not a solution